# If else statement doing the oposite of what itis supposed to! Java

Tags: java, if-statement

Java problem I believe there is a quick fix to:

```
public void setFlappyBirdHighScore(int newFlappyBirdHighScore) {
    if(newFlappyBirdHighScore > 999 || newFlappyBirdHighScore != 999) 
    {
        if(newFlappyBirdHighScore == flappyBirdHighScore) {
            System.out.println("The new score is the same as the old high score, please enter yor new high score");
        }
        else {
            flappyBirdHighScore = newFlappyBirdHighScore;
            System.out.println("Your new FlappyBird High Score is: " +newFlappyBirdHighScore);
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("You have to many digits in your score, please use 1-3 digits.");
    }
}
```

Now it prints the last else statement when there is less than or 999, but i want it to say the opposite. If the entered digits are above 999 i want it to print the last statement, the other two works just fine. other than this small problem, any fast solutions?

Comment: It does the opposite of what you expect it to do but it definitely does what it's supposed to do. Don't word your questions like that.

Comment: Read the first `if` condition out loud, and then think about whether it makes sense...

Comment: Did you intend one of the `newFlappyBirdHighScore` variables in the first `if` to be a `flappyBirdHighScore`? It's not making much sense as it is.

Comment: The only way the first `if` will fail is if `newFlappyBirdHighScore` is 999. If it has any other value at all, it will meet the conditions. The rest of the code doesn't make a whole lot of sense, either.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

`if(newFlappyBirdHighScore > 999 || newFlappyBirdHighScore != 999)`

What you are saying is that unless the score equals 999, do the last else statement.

You'd have more luck with:

```
 if(newFlappyBirdHighScore <= 999)
```

Comment: OP want's to go into the first if-statment if the entered digit is less than or equal to 999. According to that statement, you want that to be a less than sign.